# DNN Site Traffic

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, logfile-analysis, high-traffic

We recently launched a web site developed with DNN.

Analyzing the log files, I see files with .axd extension as resources accessed together with pages. The problem is that I see a heavy traffic on these .axd files.

By heavy traffic, I mean hits, visits and data transferred.

My questions are:
1- Why do I see these .axd files within the pages accessed, while in the old site made with normal .net, I never saw them?
Samples of these files names:WebResource.axd, DXR.axd, ScriptResource.axd

2- Do the hits, visits and data transferred I see on these .axd files count? In other words, if a page named "abc.aspx" is using WebResource.axd to load, then to get the total visitors on abc.aspx, I shall add both visitors up (those of .aspx and those of .axd?

3- Do the hits, visits and data transferred I see on these .axd files give me a false total traffic value? Actually, the traffic became suddenly 40% higher while I noticed that visitors and hits went much lower.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The AXD files are essentially DNN and ASP.NET handling resources, mainly javascript. Just as with other JS files, they are items loaded on a page request, so I would filter these out of  "hits" analysis.

Comment: And is it the same for the GB traffic?

Comment: Do you mean the bandwidth associated with those files?